# How do I get onsite DNS to communicate with Azure VNet DNS?

Tags: internal-dns, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

We have an S2S and our DNS server in Azure can talk with the Azure VNET DNS, however our onsite DNS server cannot because of a routing issue I think.

What configuration do I need to change so that requests from our local DNS server forwarding to `168.63.129.16` go through our S2S connection to the Azure VNET?  I already have the conditional forwarder added for `core.windows.net`.

We have a Meraki if you need to know that.

Comment: Instead of adding `168.63.129.16` to the conditional forwarder on the local DNS, I added the local IP of the DNS server in Azure which then conditional forwards to `168.63.129.16`.  That seems to be working but is a single point of failure.  I'd like to be able to do it the right way.

Comment: Azure Private DNS Resolver is now in preview which will let you do what you want